# Word to describe someone who plays 'devil's advocate'

Tags: single-word-requests

Say someone regularly plays devil's advocate, arguing against whatever belief is currently espoused, even if he believes in it.  In particular the individual believes in doing this with his own beliefs as well, and regularly mentally argues against a belief he holds to ensure they are reasonable and not skewed by bias.

Is there a word to describe a person who does this, or the belief in the importance of doing this with one's own beliefs?

Is there a word to refer to the act of arguing against your personal beliefs, particularly in situations where the argument is done internally, purely to verify the validity of the belief, rather then externally as part of a debate or discussion with others?

Edit:

to clarify I'm trying to avoid negative connotations, looking for either value neutral or positive word.  The focus should be on questioning ideas as a path towards checking biases, flawed logic, or simply finding missed arguments against that may change one's judgement; with the ultimate goal of ensuring a more informed final decision.  Or in short, a way to avoid personal dogma clouding reason.

Comment: Wouldn't such people be called *skeptical*?

Comment: A "contrarian" mostly meets the definition.

Comment: *Argumentative* might fit.

Comment: Updated the question to state that I was looking for a word with a value neutral or positive tendency,  sorry should have thought of that sooner :)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy hmm, skeptic sort of works, but it does bring in other connotations as well, like potentially implying higher degree of pessimism, or in some cases it may be associated with anti-religion or otherwise more active advocating of viewpoints, due to many of the verbal groups that refer to themselves as skeptics (and those words have slightly wrong connotation, I'm trying only to describe the goal of 'skeptic' groups that I've seen but feel I'm using the wrong words that give the wrong impression of the groups lol)  In any case it is not a bad option, in some cases I may use it.

Comment: @elian in my experience politicians tend to argue rather dogmatic view points with lots of rhetoric tricks designed to avoid direct discussion of their platform, and in particular of potential flaws of it.  In short politicians seem to be the opposite of what I'm expressing, a large part of checking one's own views would be to screen against rhetoric!

Comment: If it must be neutral, then 'defense' works but has very little of the connotation of _devil_'s advocate.

Comment: My first thought was “analytical”, possibly followed by “logical”.  These may *describe* a devil's advocate, but they are not *synonymous* with devil's advocate, and don't carry the same connotations.  (P.S. “Impartial” isn't what you're looking for, is it?)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I scanned over the old comments after someone posted a new one and remembered your suggestion for skeptic.  At the time I dismissed it as not perfect, but at the time I really thought there would exist a good term for what I described which hasn't come up.  In restrospect your suggestion *is* the best one made, and in fact I feel my original hesitation was unfounded as whatever other meanings skeptics has this is *one of* it's meanings.  if you wanted to post it as an answer I'd accept it over the current answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two words that are synonyms of devil's advocate, however neither is commonly used and one actually has a negative connotation.

The first is [polemicist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/polemicist).  This one carries an implication of (viciously) attacking another's point of view, so this is not what you want.

The second is [apologist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apologist).  This term is slightly more neutral, referring to someone who defends a position that is being attacked by others.  It might work, it might not.

In my opinion, the best term to use to describe this person is the original term: devil's advocate.

Comment: I agree, the original phrase of "devil's advocate" carries the exact meanings and associations desired by the OP.

Comment: Neither is quite what I like, but as others keep pointing out apparntly I'm not the only one who can't find the right phrase.  I'm accepting this because it did it's best to address what I was looking for despite the difficulty, and because it taught me a new word I didn't know before that I likely will use at some point :)

Comment: Here's a word:  dissenter

Answer (score 2):

How about "gadfly"?
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_gadfly):

A gadfly is a person who interferes with the status quo of a society or community by posing novel, potently upsetting questions, usually directed at authorities. The term is originally associated with the ancient Greek philosopher Socrates, in his defense when on trial for his life.

Comment: not really the same thing, but I admit there are times it could work well, and it's just plan fun word to use, so I'll probably use it at some point :)  I already knew it, but you make me realize I really should try to incorporate it into my spoken vocabulary more ;)

Comment: thinking it ove rmore I'm close to selecting this as the correct answer, as it's the term I'm most likely to use in my actual daily life when trying to describe something close to the orriginal idea.  While I feel it's less exact then some terms it's also better known, it's the one term I could see myself using and expecting other's to understand (plus, it fits into my personal slightly self-depricating humor about myself to call myself a gadfly).  But I already selected an answer and should stick with the most accurate, the fact thta the word fits my personality seems unfair bias for choosing

Answer (score 1):

That it is difficult to find neutral let alone positive terms speaks volumes about our language. Devoted self-questioner, positive skeptic, skillful doubter, rational Buddhist.

Comment: Question is a single-word-request. Recommended action is to edit answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Id like to propose a new word to describe this idea as apologist or polemicist don't quite fit the bill.
Dadvist = Someone who often plays devil's advocate, but in a neutral non religious connotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Caleb.  Neologisms are off topic; we're looking for established terms.  I encourage you to see the [help] and the site [tour].

Comment: "Devocate". There might be a reason no portmanteau exists yet.

Comment: No explicit request to avoid inventing new words but "is there a" suggests it is looking for an already-existing word that has wide acceptance.